# Set android:altSrc programmatically in ImageFilterView?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

this is my layout element.

```
<android.support.constraint.utils.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/start_track"
        android:layout_width="96dp" android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons_copy_6"
        app:altSrc="@drawable/icons_copy_4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

and in Activity, I'm initializing this view as below.

```
ImageFilterView thumb = v.findViewById(R.id.start_thumb);
```

I'm able to set the image src as below

```
thumb.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mThumbDisabled));
```

**How do I set `app:altSrc="@drawable/icons_copy_4"` Dynamically ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a custom view which extends AppCompatImageView

```
public class CustomImageFilterView extends AppCompatImageView {

float[] m = new float[20];
ColorMatrix mColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
ColorMatrix mTmpColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
private float mSaturation = 1.0F;
private float mContrast = 1.0F;
private float mWarmth = 1.0F;
private float mCrossfade = 0.0F;
private AttributeSet attributeSet;
Drawable[] mLayers;
LayerDrawable mLayer;


public CustomImageFilterView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init(context, (AttributeSet)null);
}

public CustomImageFilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomImageFilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this.attributeSet = attrs;
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = this.getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomImageFilterView);
        int N = a.getIndexCount();
        Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomImageFilterView_customDrawable);

        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            int attr = a.getIndex(i);
            if (attr == android.support.constraint.R.styleable.ImageFilterView_crossfade) {
                this.mCrossfade = a.getFloat(attr, 0.0F);
            }
        }

        a.recycle();
        if (drawable != null) {
            this.mLayers = new Drawable[2];
            this.mLayers[0] = this.getDrawable();
            this.mLayers[1] = drawable;
            this.mLayer = new LayerDrawable(this.mLayers);
            this.mLayer.getDrawable(1).setAlpha((int)(255.0F * this.mCrossfade));
            super.setImageDrawable(this.mLayer);
        }
    }

}

public void setAltDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    TypedArray a = this.getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CustomImageFilterView);
    int N = a.getIndexCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        if (attr == android.support.constraint.R.styleable.ImageFilterView_crossfade) {
            this.mCrossfade = a.getFloat(attr, 0.0F);
        }
    }

    a.recycle();
    if (drawable != null) {
        this.mLayers = new Drawable[2];
        this.mLayers[0] = this.getDrawable();
        this.mLayers[1] = drawable;
        this.mLayer = new LayerDrawable(this.mLayers);
        this.mLayer.getDrawable(1).setAlpha((int)(255.0F * this.mCrossfade));
        super.setImageDrawable(this.mLayer);
    }
}

public void setSaturation(float saturation) {
    this.mSaturation = saturation;
    this.updateMatrix();
}

public float getSaturation() {
    return this.mSaturation;
}

public void setContrast(float contrast) {
    this.mContrast = contrast;
    this.updateMatrix();
}

public float getContrast() {
    return this.mContrast;
}

public void setWarmth(float warmth) {
    this.mWarmth = warmth;
    this.updateMatrix();
}

public float getWarmth() {
    return this.mWarmth;
}

public void setCrossfade(float crossfade) {
    this.mCrossfade = crossfade;
    if (this.mLayers != null) {
        this.mLayer.getDrawable(1).setAlpha((int)(255.0F * this.mCrossfade));
        super.setImageDrawable(this.mLayer);
    }

}

public float getCrossfade() {
    return this.mCrossfade;
}

private void saturation(float saturationStrength) {
    float Rf = 0.2999F;
    float Gf = 0.587F;
    float Bf = 0.114F;
    float MS = 1.0F - saturationStrength;
    float Rt = Rf * MS;
    float Gt = Gf * MS;
    float Bt = Bf * MS;
    this.m[0] = Rt + saturationStrength;
    this.m[1] = Gt;
    this.m[2] = Bt;
    this.m[3] = 0.0F;
    this.m[4] = 0.0F;
    this.m[5] = Rt;
    this.m[6] = Gt + saturationStrength;
    this.m[7] = Bt;
    this.m[8] = 0.0F;
    this.m[9] = 0.0F;
    this.m[10] = Rt;
    this.m[11] = Gt;
    this.m[12] = Bt + saturationStrength;
    this.m[13] = 0.0F;
    this.m[14] = 0.0F;
    this.m[15] = 0.0F;
    this.m[16] = 0.0F;
    this.m[17] = 0.0F;
    this.m[18] = 1.0F;
    this.m[19] = 0.0F;
}

private void warmth(float warmth) {
    float baseTemprature = 5000.0F;
    if (warmth <= 0.0F) {
        warmth = 0.01F;
    }

    float kelvin = baseTemprature / warmth;
    float color_r = kelvin / 100.0F;
    float color_g;
    float color_b;
    float colorR;
    if (color_r > 66.0F) {
        colorR = color_r - 60.0F;
        color_g = 329.69873F * (float)Math.pow((double)colorR, -0.13320475816726685D);
        color_b = 288.12216F * (float)Math.pow((double)colorR, 0.07551484555006027D);
    } else {
        color_b = 99.4708F * (float)Math.log((double)color_r) - 161.11957F;
        color_g = 255.0F;
    }

    float centiKelvin;
    if (color_r < 66.0F) {
        if (color_r > 19.0F) {
            centiKelvin = 138.51773F * (float)Math.log((double)(color_r - 10.0F)) - 305.0448F;
        } else {
            centiKelvin = 0.0F;
        }
    } else {
        centiKelvin = 255.0F;
    }

    float tmpColor_r = Math.min(255.0F, Math.max(color_g, 0.0F));
    float tmpColor_g = Math.min(255.0F, Math.max(color_b, 0.0F));
    float tmpColor_b = Math.min(255.0F, Math.max(centiKelvin, 0.0F));
    color_r = tmpColor_r;
    color_g = tmpColor_g;
    color_b = tmpColor_b;
    centiKelvin = baseTemprature / 100.0F;
    float colorG;
    if (centiKelvin > 66.0F) {
        float tmp = centiKelvin - 60.0F;
        colorR = 329.69873F * (float)Math.pow((double)tmp, -0.13320475816726685D);
        colorG = 288.12216F * (float)Math.pow((double)tmp, 0.07551484555006027D);
    } else {
        colorG = 99.4708F * (float)Math.log((double)centiKelvin) - 161.11957F;
        colorR = 255.0F;
    }

    float colorB;
    if (centiKelvin < 66.0F) {
        if (centiKelvin > 19.0F) {
            colorB = 138.51773F * (float)Math.log((double)(centiKelvin - 10.0F)) - 305.0448F;
        } else {
            colorB = 0.0F;
        }
    } else {
        colorB = 255.0F;
    }

    tmpColor_r = Math.min(255.0F, Math.max(colorR, 0.0F));
    tmpColor_g = Math.min(255.0F, Math.max(colorG, 0.0F));
    tmpColor_b = Math.min(255.0F, Math.max(colorB, 0.0F));
    color_r /= tmpColor_r;
    color_g /= tmpColor_g;
    color_b /= tmpColor_b;
    this.m[0] = color_r;
    this.m[1] = 0.0F;
    this.m[2] = 0.0F;
    this.m[3] = 0.0F;
    this.m[4] = 0.0F;
    this.m[5] = 0.0F;
    this.m[6] = color_g;
    this.m[7] = 0.0F;
    this.m[8] = 0.0F;
    this.m[9] = 0.0F;
    this.m[10] = 0.0F;
    this.m[11] = 0.0F;
    this.m[12] = color_b;
    this.m[13] = 0.0F;
    this.m[14] = 0.0F;
    this.m[15] = 0.0F;
    this.m[16] = 0.0F;
    this.m[17] = 0.0F;
    this.m[18] = 1.0F;
    this.m[19] = 0.0F;
}

private void updateMatrix() {
    this.mColorMatrix.reset();
    boolean filter = false;
    if (this.mSaturation != 1.0F) {
        this.saturation(this.mSaturation);
        this.mColorMatrix.set(this.m);
        filter = true;
    }

    if (this.mContrast != 1.0F) {
        this.mTmpColorMatrix.setScale(this.mContrast, this.mContrast, this.mContrast, 1.0F);
        this.mColorMatrix.postConcat(this.mTmpColorMatrix);
        filter = true;
    }

    if (this.mWarmth != 1.0F) {
        this.warmth(this.mWarmth);
        this.mTmpColorMatrix.set(this.m);
        this.mColorMatrix.postConcat(this.mTmpColorMatrix);
        filter = true;
    }

    if (filter) {
        this.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(this.mColorMatrix));
    } else {
        this.clearColorFilter();
    }

}
```

and create a custom style

```
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="CustomImageFilterView">

    <attr name="customDrawable" format="reference" />

</declare-styleable>
```

The custom view class has a setter method which sets the alt drawable dynamically
**setAltDrawable** pass the drawable and voila.